# Adding value from inflated EditText to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-edittext

I am new to programming, so please forgive if this is stupid question.
I have two buttons. First adds EditText to Activity, second saves entered value to array. The problem is that it saves value only from first EditText. As a result, if I want to sum all values from the array, I will get first value multiplied by number of added EditTexts. Thank you in advance.

```
ArrayList<EditText> editText2ArrayList = new ArrayList<EditText>();
int j = 0;
```

Button that adds EditText

```
public void addButtonMethod(View view){
        ImageButton addButton = findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        ImageButton confirmButton = findViewById(R.id.confirmButton);
        LinearLayout itemList = findViewById(R.id.AddLayout);
        View item = LayoutInflater.from(this)
                .inflate(R.layout.add_textview, itemList, false);
        itemList.addView(item);
        confirmButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        addButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray_round_button);
        addButton.setClickable(false);
        EditText addEditText2 = findViewById(R.id.add_edit_text_2);   // this is EditText from R.layout.add_textview
        editText2ArrayList.add(j, addEditText2);
    }
```

Button that confirms entered text

```
public void confirmButtonMethod(View view){
        ImageButton addButton = findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        ImageButton confirmButton = findViewById(R.id.confirmButton);
        EditText currentAddEditText2 = editText2ArrayList.get(j);
        j++;
        if(currentAddEditText2.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0){
            String priceString = currentAddEditText2.getText().toString();
            Float price = Float.parseFloat(priceString);
            productPrices.add(price);
            confirmButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            addButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_button);
            addButton.setClickable(true);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter the price", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

Comment: You should change your approach and use a `RecyclerView` or a `ListView`

Comment: Please show the whole activity/fragment where these methods are contained.